# Change key pair for AWS EC2 instance after initial launch using "View/Change User Data" option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, key-pair

I created and started EC2 instance in AWS a couple of weeks ago. Unfortunately, lost my private key and tried to add another key pair following [Replace a Lost SSH Key Pair for Amazon EC2 by Using User Data](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/user-data-replace-key-pair-ec2/) from Amazon.

I wonder if anyone managed to apply that solution successfully? Maybe there is a mistake in step #5 in that article since I followed whole instruction precisely, but I'm still getting my newly created private key denied while trying to log into my EC2 instance.

P.S. "keypair" was replaced with full public key I got from `ssh-keygen -y -f MyNewPrivateKey.pem` output.

Comment: The solution worked fine for me. I tried a couple of AMIs: Amazon Linux and Ubuntu image. Your image (AMI) could probably have a custom SSH configuration that might prevent this solution from not working.

Comment: @SergeyLitvin - you finally changed it, didn't you? what do you mean by "with full public key"? the full name, like my-key.pem? or the whole key by itself?

Comment: @JohnK 1. By "full public key" I meant the whole key as it is. 2. I didn't manage to implement that approach on my existing EC2 instance, most likely as "krishna_mee2004" mentioned in the above comment, due to non-standard ssh_config file, however, can't prove it since I reached out to AWS support in order to get some hints on possible causes, but haven't received any reply yet. Just can confirm that instruction worked fine for newly created instances for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create .pem key pair then downloaded the .pem file and upload it into the s3 bucket and take uri of the object for step 2).

NOTE: at step 5) `" <PEM-FILE-NAME>"` prifix space is required.

```
1) $ sudo su
2) $ cd /home/ec2-user && aws s3 cp <URI-OF-S3-UPLODED-PEM-FILE> .
3) $ chmod 600 /home/ec2-user/<PEM-FILE-NAME>.pem
4) $ out=$(ssh-keygen -f <PEM-FILE-NAME>.pem -y)
5) $ key=" <PEM-FILE-NAME>"
6) $ out+=$key
7) $ echo $out 
8) $ echo $out > /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
9) $ reboot
```

Hope it helps you!